# Express router ID question - Reading text as ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have two routes where after each route you can type an ID, and get the specific ID of that restaurant (ignore all the misspellings.. I know) back,

If I type /all it's like it's trying to get /all as an ID..

I'm sure it's something small and I know it is weird to get an ID from being on both routes, but.. whatever, I am new to Express, and well JS an all only about 8 weeks into coding in general.

resaruants.js route -

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    restaruantModel = require('../models/restaruantModel');

router.get('/:rid?', async (req, res) => {
    const { rid } = req.params;
    let restaruantData = [];

    if (!!rid) {
        restaruantData = await restaruantModel.getById(rid);
    } else {
        restaruantData = await restaruantModel.getAll();
    };

    res.render ('template', {
        locals: {
            title: 'Restaruants',
            dataArray: restaruantData
        },
        partials : {
            partial: 'partial-index'
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

allTheRestaruants.js (Spelling is hard) - router :

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    restaruantModel = require('../models/restaruantModel');

router.get('/:id?', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let restaruantData = [];

    if (!!id) {
        restaruantData = await restaruantModel.getById(id);
    } else {
        restaruantData = await restaruantModel.getAll();
    };


    res.render ('template', {
        locals: {
            title: 'All The Restaruants',
            dataArray: restaruantData
        },
        partials : {
            partial: 'partial-all'
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've narrowed the code down.. I am pretty sure to being in my routes.

TLDR ;

/all route doesn't work, reading "all" as an ID from the index. 
Searching by the ID does work tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same route with the same option `resaruants.js` route is **exactly** the same as `allTheRestaruants.js`

it would only worked if:

```
const resRoute = require('./routes/resaruants')
const resAllRoute = require('./routes/allTheRestaruants')
...
app.use('/restaurant', resRoute)
app.use('/restaurant-all', resAllRoute)
```

giving you 2 routes.

But, I'm assuming you're trying to do a REST API, the idea is that, when you pass no `id` you automatically get all, so no need to specify all, for example:

a simple `restaurants.js` routing file

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const restaruantModel = require('../models/restaruantModel');

const sendData = (res, dataArray, title) => {
    res.render ('template', {
        locals: {
            title,
            dataArray
        },
        partials : {
            partial: 'partial-all'
        }
    });
}

const getAll = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await restaruantModel.getAll();
    sendData(res, data, 'All The Restaruants')
}

const getById = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const data = await restaruantModel.getById(id);
    sendData(res, data, 'Restaruant #' + id)
}

router.get('/restaurants', getAll)
router.get('/restaurants/:id', getById)

module.exports = router;
```

it is easier to read, and you do something that you should always aim: separation of concerns

this way, a `GET /restaurants` will get you all (you better add paging as well later on) and `GET /restaurants/23` will get only the restaurant #23...

---

BTW, if you use Visual Studio, as English is not my mother language, and I love to write code in English so all can read property, I use [Code spell checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) plugin :)

Comment: Thank you, and my native language is english I restaurant is just one of those words ha. I ended up just changing the whole index page to have a " restaurant of the day " because it didn't really make sense to have two pages listing all the places.